# The smallest and the largest possible date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date

I am creating a filtering partial view, where user can pick a `from`-date and a `to`-date using a calendar. These dates are used then within model scope to perform SQL `Where` clause in database query. If a user does not pick one of dates, the default value should be assigned: minimal available date for `from` and maximal for `to`.

```
unless params[:from].blank? and params[:to].blank?
   from = begin Date.parse(params[:from]) rescue ??? end
   to = begin Date.parse(params[:to]) rescue ??? end
   @model_instances = @model_instances.start_end from, to
end
```

(...)

```
scope :start_end, -> (start_date, end_date) { where('(:start_date <= "from" AND "from" <= :end_date ) OR' +
                                              '(:start_date <= "to" AND "to" <= :end_date ) OR' +
                                              '("from" <= :start_date AND :end_date <= "to")',
                                               {start_date: start_date, end_date: end_date}) }
```

The `from` and `to` model Date attributes are also database fields in related table.

In Rails, `Date` class has a family of methods `beginning_of` (day, week, month, etc.), but there are no methods such `beginning_of_time`, `end_of_time`, `Date.min`, `Date.max`.

Are there any methods to obtain the minimal and maximal dates?

Comment: you could just skip this process if no `params[:from]` or `params[:to]` is given, so any date would match the query

Comment: @MrYoshiji I added the model scope code. I need that my SQL query works even if only one of date is picked by user.

Comment: You can split your `start_end` scope into two distinct scopes `start_before` and `end_before` if only one of the two dates is provided, and if the two are provided use `start_end` scope. I think it is the best way to go because in this case you don't "try to guess a date not provided by the end user"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could skip the condition on `start` and `end` dates if no params is given:

```
if params[:from].present? and params[:to].present?
  @model_instances.start_end(params[:from], params[:to]) 
end
```

And then you will get results not depending on dates since no `from` and/or `end` dates have been filled.

Answer (score 0):

You could compare ranges of dates to your model's values and setup default values if params not passed.

```
#setup default if desired, or you can skip if params are blank
from = params[:from] || default_from
to = params[:to] || default_to
@model_instances.start_end(from, to)
```

and your scope would look something like this if you used date ranges for activerecord

```
scope :start_end, ->(start_date, end_date){where(from: start_date..end_date, to:start_date..end_date)}
```